# Posting Message using Facebook API

Tags: php

Couldn't find this anywhere on Stack overflow, I just don't know what to do.

I just want to place a message on my community Facebook page using the Facebook PHP API, where to get started?

Example:
I click a button on my website, which then automatically posts 'I clicked the button' on my Facebook (community) page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi/4.0.0) for what you need.

```
$session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
        'link' => 'www.example.com',
        'message' => 'User provided message'
      )
```

Change `/me/feed` to the page you want.

Comment: 'This example covers posting a link to the current user's timeline using the Graph API and Facebook SDK for PHP.' I want to place the message (link) on my Own timeline of my community page.